# Change date format in Rails validates_timeliness error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

The [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) gem says it supports I18n for its error messages. However, I can't find any configuration (or documentation) to show me how to modify the date format on error messages it generates.

There is a `DEFAULT_ERROR_VALUE_FORMATS` in the gem's `validator.rb` file. However, I don't want a global change -- I need to format error messages per locale.

I've tried adding the relevant I18n date format block to my application's `config/locales` language files, like so:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

However, that has no effect after server restart.

So my question: how can I apply a locale-specific date to the error messages that the validates_timeliness gem generates?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that `validates_timeliness` has its own locale block which it defines in `lib/generators/validates_timeliness/templates/en.yml`, and to change format you need to override that block.

Add the following block to the locale file(s) in your application's `config/locales` directory:

```
en:
  validates_timeliness:
    error_value_formats:
      date: '%m/%d/%Y'
      time: '%H:%M:%S'
      datetime: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

The formatted sections can be any valid [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)-formatted string.

This answer specifically applies to a Rails 3.2 and validates_timeliness 3.0.14 environment, but likely applies generally.